# Elasticsearch is still initializing the kibana index

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

When I am trying to start Kibana I am facing the following issue. I first restarted my elasticsearch server it was running successfully. After starting Elasticsearch I tried to start Kibana but no luck.

```
{"name":"Kibana","hostname":"ABCD","pid":3848,"level":30,"msg":"Elasticsearch is still initializing the kibana index... Trying again in 2.5 second.","time":"2015-07-03T07:35:34.936Z","v":0}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 65, accepted):

> Warning: Removing `.kibana` index will make you **lose** all your kibana settings (indexes, graphs, dashboards)

This behavior is sometimes caused by an existing `.kibana` index.
Kindly delete the `.kibana` index in elasticsearch using following command:

```
curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/.kibana
```

After deleting the index, restart Kibana.

If the problem still persists, *and you are willing to lose any existing data*, you can try deleting all indexes using following command:

```
curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/*
```

Followed by restarting Kibana.

Note: `localhost:9200` is the elasticsearch server's `host:port`, which may be different in your case.

Comment: Yes I did the same procedure now its working now. I don't why index was crashing. Any how thanks for the help dude.

Comment: Where is this .kibana stored?

Comment: It is stored inside elasticsearch-version/data/clustername/nodes/nodeno/indices folder.

Comment: Please also note @gaellm 's answer below which does *NOT* require deleting the index.

Comment: Everything is lost after DELETE indexes...that's an important sideoff effect :S

Comment: This answer should not be the correct one @Mangoski, as it is destructive. The answer provided below is non-destructive and is the correct one.

Comment: Downvoted, because @gaellm 's answer should work in most cases. That should always be tried first. Deleting the index is only a last resort solution even if you have hot backups.

Comment: I got a bad gateway error after this. But it worked once I restarted all of the elk services.

Answer (score 81):

the `curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/.kibana` command works fine, however you lose all your Kibana settings (indexes, graphs, dashboards); by just querying the index I've solved the problem, without losing my data. For example:

```
curl -s http://localhost:9200/.kibana/_recovery?pretty
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/.kibana/_settings' -d '
{
    "index" : {
        "number_of_replicas" : 0
    }
}'
```

Then start Kibana, it should work.

Gael Le Moellic

Comment: I only ran the first curl statement and it worked for me. No idea why. Would love an explanation/more details if possible.

Comment: with ES 6 and above, you'll probably need to add `-H 'Content-Type: application/json'` to the second curl command -- [see the announcement](https://www.elastic.co/blog/strict-content-type-checking-for-elasticsearch-rest-requests)

Comment: life safer, just the first curl request works if you deleted your .kibana index, works also on opensearch

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes you need to wait few minutes after restarting ES.
That can be also connected with low disk space.
Observed on AWS t2.small machine with ELK stack.

Comment: What would be a few minutes? 5? 15? 30? Not trying to be mean, but just want to know what 'normal' is.

Comment: Rough below 10min for t2.small and 50GB of data in ES. Depends from to many factors to estimate :)

Answer (score -2):

Something is wrong with your Kibana index inside elasticsearch.
I had the same message and i just deleted my Kibana index and then,
when i restarted it, a new index of Kibana was created by the service.