# Elasticsearch is still initializing the kibana index. Deleting an index doesn't hеlp

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have two servers: Kibana is installed on one of them and Elasticsearch is installed on another one.

The Kibana's version is 4.5.4
The Elastic version is 2.3.1

Here is what I get when I start kibana

```
  log   [07:25:26.859] [info][status][plugin:kibana] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [07:25:26.890] [info][status][plugin:elasticsearch] Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch
  log   [07:25:26.905] [info][status][plugin:kbn_vislib_vis_types] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [07:25:26.913] [info][status][plugin:markdown_vis] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [07:25:26.919] [info][status][plugin:metric_vis] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [07:25:26.923] [info][status][plugin:spyModes] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [07:25:26.940] [info][status][plugin:statusPage] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [07:25:26.945] [info][status][plugin:table_vis] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [07:25:26.950] [error][status][plugin:elasticsearch] Status changed from yellow to red - Elasticsearch is still initializing the kibana index.
  log   [07:25:26.952] [info][listening] Server running at http://0.0.0.0:5601
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201051/elasticsearch-is-still-initializing-the-kibana-index) answer I delete an index file in elasticsearch.

Then I restart kibana and elastic, and here is what I get in the log, when I try to start kibana.

```
  log   [07:29:57.455] [info][status][plugin:kibana] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [07:29:57.488] [info][status][plugin:elasticsearch] Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch
  log   [07:29:57.502] [error][elasticsearch] Request error, retrying -- connect ECONNREFUSED 10.205.102.36:9200
  log   [07:29:57.508] [warning][elasticsearch] Unable to revive connection: http://10.205.102.36:9200/
  log   [07:29:57.509] [warning][elasticsearch] No living connections
  log   [07:29:57.511] [error][status][plugin:elasticsearch] Status changed from yellow to red - Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at http://10.205.102.36:9200.
  log   [07:29:57.512] [info][status][plugin:kbn_vislib_vis_types] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [07:29:57.516] [info][status][plugin:markdown_vis] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [07:29:57.519] [info][status][plugin:metric_vis] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [07:29:57.529] [info][status][plugin:spyModes] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [07:29:57.533] [info][status][plugin:statusPage] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [07:29:57.536] [info][status][plugin:table_vis] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [07:29:57.542] [info][listening] Server running at http://0.0.0.0:5601
  log   [07:30:05.102] [info][status][plugin:elasticsearch] Status changed from red to yellow - No existing Kibana index found
  log   [07:30:35.288] [error][status][plugin:elasticsearch] Status changed from yellow to red - Waiting for Kibana index ".kibana" to come online failed.
  log   [07:30:37.803] [error][status][plugin:elasticsearch] Status changed from red to red - Elasticsearch is still initializing the kibana index.
```

So when I delete an index, it creates it again and shows the same error. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the corresponding elasticsearch logs. I assume that elasticsearch has some issues and you only observe some subsequent errors in kibana.

Comment: how to do it? I am totally new in it.

Comment: Depends on how you start elasticsearch. It could be similar to getting the logs for kibana. Either console output when running the start script, log files in the installation directory or service logs. How do you start your elasticsearch instance?

Comment: By using command "service elasticsearch start"

Comment: When installed as a service the default path to the elasticsearch logs is /var/log/elasticsearch. Please have a look for the files there...